Creating a yearly training log with calendar.sty and loops
I'm quite new to LaTeX and just playing around learning new things.
So i want to create a PDF that i can print as a book to log my training and still be able to write some things with a pen. It should look like this:  just for all months and then for the weeks within that month separately. I created the example without the loops just fine, but i seems like calendar.sty has some kind of interaction with the loop packages.
This is the not working code:
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{calendar} 
\usepackage{parallel,enumitem}
\usepackage[landscape, a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepackage{forloop} 
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font

\begin{document}

\def\MonthArr{ % array for "index", "monthname", "blankdays" and "days of month"
{{"1","January","0","31"}},
{{"2","February","3","29"}},
%{{"3","March","4","31"}},
%{{"4","April","0","30"}},
%{{"5","May","2","31"}},
%{{"6","June","4","30"}},
%{{"7","July","0","31"}},
%{{"8","August","3","31"}},
%{{"9","September","1","30"}},
%{{"10","October","1","31"}},
%{{"11","November","3","30"}},
%{{"12","December","1","31"}}
}
\foreach \Month in \MonthArr {
  
    \StartingDayNumber=2 

    \begin{center}
       \textsc{\LARGE \pgfmathparse{\Month[2]}\pgfmathresult}\\ % Month
        \textsc{\large 2024} % Year
    \end{center}

    \begin{calendar}{\textwidth} 

    \newcounter{x} 
    \forloop{x}{0}{\value{x}<\pgfmathparse{\Month[2]}\pgfmathresult}{
        \BlankDay
    } 

    \setcounter{calendardate}{1} % Start the date counter at 1
    \newcounter{days}{0}
    \def\DayArr{
    {{"Level 8","easy non-crimp boulders of new set \eventskip chinups \eventskip stretching"}}, % day 1
    {{"Level 8","new set \dayheader{Notes:}{}"}}, % day 2
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 3
    {{"Hangboard","\dayheader{Notes:}{}"}},% day 4
    {{"Strength","weighted Pullups \eventskip Deadlifts \eventskip Benchpulls \eventskip Flys \eventskip Muscleups"}},% day 5
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 6
    {{"Kilterboard","Notes:"}},% day 7
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 8
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 9
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 10
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 11
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 12
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 13
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 14
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 15
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 16
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 17
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 18
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 19
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 20
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 21
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 22
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 23
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 24
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 25
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 26
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 27
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 28
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 29
    {{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 30
    %{{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 31
    %{{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 32
    %{{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 33
    %{{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 34
    %{{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 34
    %{{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 35
    %{{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 36
    %{{"~","\vspace{2.5cm}"}},% day 37
    }
    \foreach [count=\i] \dayarr in \DayArr { %body
            \day{\pgfmathparse{\dayarr[0]}\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathparse{\dayarr[2]}\pgfmathresult}
            \ifnum \i=\pgfmathparse{\Month[3]}\pgfmathresult
                \breakforeach
            \fi    
            %\breakforeach
    }
    \finishCalendar
    \end{calendar}
    \newpage
} % closing bracket of the BIG foreach-loop
\end{document}

This are the errors:

Undefined control sequence.  \pgfmath@catcodes ...`\|=12 \catcode `\&=12 \let " \pgfmath@char@quote
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 131.

                \fi 
<*> template.tex 

I am using Overleaf to create it for now and the error messages when i comment out the forloop for the blank days at the start of a month are:

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
Missing \endgroup inserted.
Missing } inserted.
Missing number, treated as zero.
Missing \cr inserted.
Missing { inserted.
Misplaced \cr.
Missing \cr inserted.

If i comment out the inner loop i get a pdf, but calendar.sty needs \day commands to fill the monthly layout with days and that loop doesnt work. Also all errors i get are pushed at the closing bracket of the big for loop for some reason.
I think it has to do something with the control structures within the calendar.sty. Sadly i wasnt able to find enough documentation to understand why it happens...
Any help appreciated :)

Welcome. // Just some remarks. When you load tikz, most of the other packages are included: check by deleting them or commenting out. // Are you aware of tikzlibrary calendar? See the manual. // Not sure why you'll need two for-variants. If in doubt, stick with tikz' \foreach (and adjust the context). // For a strategy to localize problems, see this comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/716287/file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-next-error-perhaps-due-to-comment#comment1780443_716287

Your arrays have a trailing ,. What is package calendar? I second @MS-SPO's comment. This seems to doable with just PGF/TikZ's calendar stuff. Can you make it more clear what data you have and how it corresponds to the output? There's a lot happening here …
